# How to move TeX Live to another partition (/data)

Tags: installing, texlive, linux

I'm a LyX user. Can I move all (or most) of the TeX related files/folders to another (Linux) partition (`/data`) and so reuse that partition for LyX-TeX after OS re-install, as well as share that TeX partition between two distros (Lubuntu and Mageia LXDE)?

Answer (score 14):

The TeX Live binaries "know" the location of the TeX Live tree (files, fonts and so on), because they set implicitly some environment variables whose value depends on the location of the binaries themselves.

On a Unix system it's so sufficient that the `PATH` environment variable contains a pointer to the binaries, for example something like

```
/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

(How to set the `PATH` variable is very system dependent). If you want to move the TeX Live tree to a `/data` partition, do it so that it's in

```
/data/texlive
```

and modify the `PATH` variable so that the location for the binaries is

```
/data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux
```

The final bit depends on the operating system, just look what's in the `texlive/2011/bin` directory to find the name.

It won't be a problem to share the tree between two GNU/Linux distributions, so long as they use the same binaries. But it's also possible to have more than one set of binaries (say the 32 bit and the 64 bit varieties): all you need is to have the correct pointer in the `PATH` variable.

A method that I find very easy to manage is to create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux /usr/texbin
```

(or `/opt/texbin` if one prefers) and use `/usr/texbin` in the PATH variable. In this way, when the update to TeX Live 2012 is available, it can be installed directly under `/data/texlive` (by modifying the default directory at installation time) and all that's needed to activate the new binaries becomes

```
rm /usr/texbin
ln -s /data/texlive/2012/bin/x86_64-linux /usr/texbin
```

(with suitable privileges, of course), without modifying the personal `.profile` file or any global file.

Similar symbolic links can be created for man pages and info files.

Comment: Thank you guys. So should I follow these steps: 1) $ mv -r /usr/local/texlive /data/texlive. 2) Edit ~/.profile like so:
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes TexLive
if [ -d "/data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux" ] ; then
PATH="/data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
fi

if [ -d "/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man" ] ; then
MANPATH="/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH"
fi

if [ -d "/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info" ] ; then
INFOPATH="/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH"
fi

Comment: @LyXTeX I wouldn't use `mv`, but rather `cp` or a `tar` based method. When you're sure that everything is OK, then you can remove the old tree.

Comment: All right, thank you. What about the rest? Correct?

Comment: @LyXTeX I guess so.

Comment: @LyXTeX Let us know whether there's any problem

Comment: No problem for the time being!

Comment: wouldn't symlinking suffice?

Comment: @egreg So just updating by tlmgr isn't going to get me Texlive 2012?

Comment: Even then it is easier for me to follow the same procedures as I'm just a noob. (It takes just a few seconds.)

Comment: @LyXTeX Until now the yearly updates of TeX Live required a new installation. I don't know if this is changing in the next release. But it has its benefits: the new release can coexist with the old one and, in case something goes wrong, we still have a working distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to egreg and [this guy on latex-community.org](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=8773) for LyX config, the steps I've taken are as follows (my architecture is x86_64):

Enter this in terminal to copy the Texlive directory:

```
cp -r /usr/local/texlive /data/texlive
```

If everything goes right you can remove the original Texlive later on.

Now edit the `~/.profile` file like so:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes TexLive
if [ -d "/data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux" ] ; then
PATH="/data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
fi

if [ -d "/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man" ] ; then
MANPATH="/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH"
fi

if [ -d "/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info" ] ; then
INFOPATH="/data/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH"
fi
```

Now to set the path to binaries in LyX, go to Tools > Preferences > Paths > PATH Prefix and enter:

```
/data/texlive/2011/bin/x86_64-linux
```

"Apply", "Save" and restart LyX. Go to "Tools > TeX Information", check "Show path" and "Rescan". If all is set correctly, LyX should find the new path. (I have simply quoted briefly the guy I've mentioned above.)

On a side note, Buntus/Debian have LyX bundled with the TeX dependency in their repositories, but that TeX part is very old (Texlive 2009). So I've installed the 3 GB Texlive 2011 and installed LyX from the terminal as it's reccomended in LyX website:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install lyx
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess from the tag `texlive` that you use texlive indeed, on a Linux machine. It may not work to use the moved installation from both Linux distributions, **if** you got *texlive* from your distribution. E.g. the *texlive* openSuse delivered (years ago) was different from the original *texlive*. Other possible error: One distribution were 32bit, other 64bit. So there are pitfalls.

*However, to me it seems recommendable to install the original 'texlive' not into /opt or /usr, but into a separate partition, e.g. /local .* You can update by `tlmgr` without interfering ẁith your package manager. You can install `texlive` independently and you can install the OS independently.

I don't recommend to install Lyx as well there. Use the Lyx your distributions deliver.

My experience from the last three years doing so is: it makes teXing easier.

Comment: Buntus/Debian has LyX bundled with the TeX dependency, but that TeX part is very old (Texlive 2009). So I've installed the 3 GB Texlive 2011 and installed LyX from the terminal as it's reccomended in LyX website: sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install lyx. Haven't tried to use it in the other distro yet, but I guess I'll do the same thinks I've done for the first one. I've already succesfully updated /data/texlive by tlmgr. What do you think? Am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Just ignore the TeX-dependency of LyX. As long as Linux knows, where TeX is, LyX works.