# Windows - Move TeX Live to another directory

Tags: texlive, windows

I'm going to move TeX Live to another directory to save space. I don't want to reinstall it.

I've read two questions here, [Moving /texlive directory to save space (Linux)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/337160/moving-texlive-directory-to-save-space-linux) and [How to move TeX Live to another partition (/data)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49936/how-to-move-tex-live-to-another-partition-data). Unfortunately, I am a Windows user, while the two questions are both about Linux.

I'd appreciate it if you've given any information or suggestions on how to solve this question.

Comment: Simply copy the whole folder, change the PATH environment variable and change the pathes in the start menu links (if you use them). If it is doesn't work you can still delete and reinstall. Btw: pretest for texlive 2023 has just started, so perhaps you can simply install the new version and later delete the old on https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do I have to do something with registry?

Comment: I don't think so but if you are worried use the official way and install a fresh copy. (If you copy better make a zip and move that. I once copied some historic texlives from one harddisk to another and it took ages if done file by file.)

Comment: I had troubles with fonts as fonts.conf contains paths to old TeXlive. Check <texlive>\2023\texmf-var\fonts\conf\fonts.conf.